# GraphQL componentPresentation null issue

Tags: graphql, pca

i am trying to run this

```
graphQL query 
{
  page (pageId: 4026, publicationId: 5, namespaceId: 1) {
    url,
    title
    rawContent(renderContent: true) {
      content
    }
  }
  componentPresentation (namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 5, componentId: 4036, templateId: 4035) {
    title
    rawContent(renderContent: true) {
      content
    }
  }
}
```

but in response componentPresentation is null, while in page response it shows, please any can help

Comment: How did you try to request this to provide bit more details of which version of Tridion?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different types of component presentations, dynamic and embedded. Embedded templates are used when a component is added to a page and published only in the context of that page. Dynamic means that the component can be published out to the broker, where it can exist as its own entity without the context of a page

Since you're saying it shows up on the page but not when querying directly for the component presentation, I would assume it's an embedded CP.

You can easily verify this by checking the component template properties:

[image: Component template options]]

Comment: yes i tried same and its working, thanks